# How to setup Git server on Linux Container in Debian

Tags: debian, git, lxc

I have a [LXC container](https://wiki.debian.org/LXC) on my Debian system. I want to setup a public Git server on it so that it's accessible to other people. How can I do this?

#### UPDATE #1

Link to `apache2.conf`: http://pastebin.com/Nvh4SsSH.

Comment: Checkout gitlab or gitorious. Not only are they easy to setup, they give you  'github' like features (pull requests ect...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this Howto a look. It's a little dated but should have the general steps you need to setup a Git server. The howto is titled: [How To Install A Public Git Repository On A Debian Server](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-a-public-git-repository-on-a-debian-server).

#### General steps

1. Install git + gitweb

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install git-core gitweb
   ```
2. Setup gitweb directories

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir /var/www/git
   $ [ -d "/var/cache/git" ] || sudo mkdir /var/cache/git
   ```
3. Setup gitweb's Apache config

   ```
   $ sudo vim /etc/apache2/conf.d/git
   ```

   contents of file:

   ```
   <Directory /var/www/git>
      Allow from all
      AllowOverride all
      Order allow,deny
      Options ExecCGI
      <Files gitweb.cgi>
      SetHandler cgi-script
       </Files>
    </Directory>
   DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
   SetEnv  GITWEB_CONFIG  /etc/gitweb.conf
   ```
4. Copy gitweb files to Apache

   ```
   $ sudo mv /usr/share/gitweb/* /var/www/git
   $ sudo mv /usr/lib/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi /var/www/git
   ```
5. Setup `gitweb.conf`

   ```
   $ sudo vim /etc/gitweb.conf
   ```

   Contents of `gitweb.conf`:

   ```
   $projectroot = '/var/cache/git/';
   $git_temp = "/tmp";
   #$home_link = $my_uri || "/";
   $home_text = "indextext.html";
   $projects_list = $projectroot;
   $stylesheet = "/git/gitweb.css";
   $logo = "/git/git-logo.png";
   $favicon = "/git/git-favicon.png";
   ```
6. Reload/Restart Apache

   ```
   $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
   ```
7. Setup Git Repository

   ```
   $ mkdir -p /var/cache/git/project.git && cd project.git
   $ git init
   ```
8. Configure Repository

   ```
   $ echo "Short project's description" > .git/description
   $ git config --global user.name "Your Name"
   $ git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
   $ git commit -a
   $ cd /var/cache/git/project.git && touch .git/git-daemon-export-ok
   ```
9. Start Git Daemon

   ```
   $ git daemon --base-path=/var/cache/git --detach --syslog --export-all
   ```
10. Test clone the Repository (from a secondary machine)

    ```
    $ git clone git://server/project.git project
    ```

#### Adding additional Repos + Users

To add more repos simply repeat steps #7 - #9. To add users just create Unix accounts for each additional user.